When an animation completes, should the "success" value be passed to "completeTransition"?
I have a class which supports UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.
Within is a func named
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)
Within that, I'm performing an animation, and doing this:
        UIView.animate(withDuration: totalDuration) {
            fromVC.view.alpha = 0
        } completion: { success in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
        }

I'm passing the boolean from the animation completion block into completeTransition. I've seen it both ways online, but I've seen a lot more people ignore that success value, and just pass in !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled.
So, the question is, what am I misinterpreting about this value? It seems that the success value has a different meaning than what is passed into completeTransition, but I'm having trouble understanding that meaning.

The answer depends on what sort of custom transition this is.

If this is a noninteractive custom transition, then just pass true to completeTransition.

If this is an interactive custom transition, then pass true if the animation finished but false if it was cancelled.


